# How to convert a datetime from sqlserver to java.util.Date

Tags: java, android, sql-server, datetime, retrofit

I am getting a row from a table with sql server database (with Asp net core as web api) using retrofit library in android and as far as I understood I must consider an string equivalent to datetime and then convert it to java.util.Date. An example of retrieved date time is `2018-10-29T19:56:59`. Is there anyway to convert datetime to java.util.Date directly?
the code is shown below.

```
public class Food {
    @SerializedName("Id")
    private long Id;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String Name;

    @SerializedName("Content")
    private String Content;

    @SerializedName("IsActive")
    private boolean IsActive;

    @SerializedName("DoesExist")
    private boolean DoesExist;

    @SerializedName("Cost")
    private int Cost;

    @SerializedName("OffPercentage")
    private int OffPercentage;

    @SerializedName("OffTimeout")
    private Date OffTimeout;
...
}
```

Comment: Could you put your JSON response data?

Comment: OffTimeout:  "2008-10-29T14:56:59"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JodaTime](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) with custom deserializer:

```
//GSON config
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeDeserializer ())
            .create();


// DateTimeDeserializer.class
    public class DateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<DateTime > {

      @Override
      public DateTime deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
          throws JsonParseException {
        return DateTime.parse(json.getAsString());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Joda-Time is probably a good idea. If you accept an external dependency, I think [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) would be an even better idea. It offers JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API AKA `java.time`, on Android, so is quite future-proof. Joda-Time is a largely finished project and now in maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1):

Change your private Date OffTimeout to String, something like this :

```
@SerializedName("OffTimeout")
private String OffTimeout;
```

And use this method to parse your date.

```
public static Date fromStringToDate(String stringDate, String pattern){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(stringDate);
            return date;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Use:

```
 Date mydate = fromStringToDate(yourOffTimeOut, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to convert it to Unix timestamp on a server before sending it. Timestamp is much more robust format for dealing with dates / times